# JAXB converts @XmlElementRefs and @XmlElements to xs:choice

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have 4 classes. `Person` class, and abstract `ContactInformation` with `Phone` and `Address` class extending it.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Person {
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = false)
    private String first;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = false)
    private String last;
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "contacts")
    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "phone", type = Phone.class, required = true),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "address", type = Address.class, required = true)
    })
    private final List<ContactInfomation> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

`ContactInformation` is used only as container:

```
public abstract class ContactInfomation { /* empty class */ }
```

`Phone` class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Phone extends ContactInfomation {
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = false)
    private String number;
}
```

And `Address` class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Address extends ContactInfomation {
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = false)
    private String country;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = false)
    private String city;
}
```

The problem is when I change `@XmlElementrefs` to `@XmlElements` in `Person` class, nothing happens. `JAXB` maps them to `xs:choice`. The XML output is same as before and `schemagen` generates the same schema as before.
Here is a sample output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<person>
    <first>majid</first>
    <last>azimi</last>
    <contacts>
        <address>
            <country>US</country>
            <city>Los Angles</city>
        </address>
        <address>
            <country>US</country>
            <city>New York</city>
        </address>
        <phone>
            <number>5551037</number>
        </phone>
    </contacts>
</person>
```

And here is the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="address" type="address"/>

  <xs:element name="person" type="person"/>

  <xs:element name="phone" type="phone"/>

  <xs:complexType name="person">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="first" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="last" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="contacts" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:element ref="phone"/>
              <xs:element ref="address"/>
            </xs:choice>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="phone">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="contactInfomation">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="number" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="contactInfomation" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="address">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="contactInfomation">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Documentation of `@XmlElementRef` uses it for Substitution group and XML choice. I'm completely confused what is the difference of `@XmlElementRefs`/`@XmlElementRef` and `@XmlElements`/`@XmlElement`. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### TL;DR

**Basic Differenece Between `@XmlElement` and `@XmlElementRef`**

The difference between `@XmlElement` and `@XmlElementRef` is if the corresponding generated element will contain a local element definition or a reference to a global element definition.

**Choice and Substitution Groups**

Choice in XML Schema is really a superset of what can be done with substitution groups.  So to simplifiy the mapping JAXB leverages one mapping for both.

**JAXB and Schema Generation**

JAXB can generated a Java model from any XML Schema, on the flip side JAXB does not preserve all metadata about the XML schema.  Therefore JAXB can't generate every XML schema.

---

### `@XmlElementRefs`/`@XmlElementRef` and `@XmlRootElement`

Below is what you have in your model.

**Person**

I have modified the mapping on the `contacts` field to make the mapping to the `Address` class more distinct.

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "contacts")
@XmlElementRefs({
    @XmlElementRef(name = "phone", type = Phone.class, required = true),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "ADDRESS", type = Address.class, required = true)
})
private final List<ContactInfomation> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Phone**

When you map with `@XmlElementRef` the information you specify needs to correspond to a global element definition supplied by `@XmlRootElement` or `@XmlElementDecl` (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html).  By default the root element for the `Person` class with be `person`.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Person {
```

**Address**

I have used the `@XmlRootElement` annotation to override the default name for the `Address class`.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ADDRESS")
public class Address extends ContactInfomation {
```

**Generated XML Schema**

Here is the generated schema.  We see that the `element` definitions within the `choice` structure leverage `ref` to reference an existing element instead of defining a local element.

```
  <xs:element name="contacts" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element ref="phone"/>
          <xs:element ref="ADDRESS"/>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

---

### `@XmlElements`/`@XmlElement`

I have changed the mapping on your `contacts` field to use `@XmlElements`.

**Person**

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "contacts")
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "phone-number", type = Phone.class, required = true),
    @XmlElement(name = "home-address", type = Address.class, required = true)
})
private final List<ContactInfomation> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Phone**

None of the referenced classes are required to be annotated with `@XmlRootElement` (or have a corresponding `@XmlElementDecl` annotation.

```
public class Phone extends ContactInfomation {
```

**Address**

If he class does have an `@XmlRootElement` annotation it is not required to match the `@XmlElement` annotation within the `@XmlElements`.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ADDRESS")
public class Address extends ContactInfomation {
```

**Generated XML Schema**

Here is the generated schema.  We see that the `element` definitions within the `choice` structure are now defined as local elements.

```
  <xs:element name="contacts" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="phone-number" type="phone"/>
          <xs:element name="home-address" type="address"/>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```